# How to Create Simple Image Slider

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The best example I can give is on the header of this subreddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/Frat/ I want to create this exact effect. Everything I google leads me to image sliders or slideshows that just replace the same image in the same location. I can't find a way to just get images to repeatedly slide as shown in the example site.

Comment: Your answer is actually right there. If thats exactly how you want the slider to look, then inspect that piece of code and find out what it is they are doing. Both chrome and firefox have excellent code inspection tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inspect the element, the below comes up. So, they've created a very long PNG image and have set "animation" to scroll.

```
#header {
background: url(//b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/mcxWBBMc21iKf16f9Zl8mzB--6d7_KL19LjnNbwfP6Q.png);
animation: scroll 200s linear infinite;
```

Answer (score 0):

To create the same effect you need to create `@keyframe` rules, so you can control the intermediate steps of the animation (in this case a transition), i made you an example: https://codepen.io/jdplee/pen/GMRNVr

You can add more rules for more steps like this:

```
@keyframes scroll {
  0% { background-position: 0 0; }
  30% { //CSS }
  68%, 72% { //CSS }
  100% { background-position: -1920px 0; }
}
```